# Visual Studio C++ reference deleted function compile error

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

If I try to compile this (Visual Studio 2015):

```
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)

//#include "readerwriterqueue.h"
#include <map>
#include <thread>

class BaseClass
{
public:
    class A {
        std::thread thd;
        //moodycamel::BlockingReaderWriterQueue<int> processqueue;
    };

    std::map<unsigned int, A> mpmap;
};  // End class BaseClass

class EXPORT_API B : public BaseClass { };
```

I get an error message about

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2280   'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function    Example C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0 737
```

Console Output:

```
    Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Example, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Example.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(737): error C2280: 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility(112): note: see declaration of 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(857): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Other>::construct<_Objty,_Ty&>(_Objty *,_Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,void *>,
1>            _Objty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(857): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Other>::construct<_Objty,_Ty&>(_Objty *,_Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,void *>,
1>            _Objty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(996): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,_Ty&>(std::allocator<_Other> &,_Objty *,_Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,void *>>,
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,
1>            _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,void *>,
1>            _Objty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(995): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,_Ty&>(std::allocator<_Other> &,_Objty *,_Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,void *>>,
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,
1>            _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,void *>,
1>            _Objty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(889): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Other>>::construct<_Ty,_Ty&>(_Ty *,_Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,void *>,
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(887): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Other>>::construct<_Ty,_Ty&>(_Ty *,_Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>,void *>,
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1939): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *std::_Tree_comp_alloc<_Traits>::_Buynode<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>&>(std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,BaseClass::A,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,false>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1939): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *std::_Tree_comp_alloc<_Traits>::_Buynode<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>&>(std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,BaseClass::A,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,false>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1966): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy_or_move<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,std::integral_constant<bool,false>>(std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &,std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy_tag,_Is_set)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,
1>            _Is_set=std::integral_constant<bool,false>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1965): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy_or_move<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,std::integral_constant<bool,false>>(std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &,std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy_tag,_Is_set)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,
1>            _Is_set=std::integral_constant<bool,false>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1921): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy_nodes<_Moveit>(std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *,std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *,_Moveit)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,
1>            _Moveit=std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,BaseClass::A,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,false>>::_Copy_tag
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1921): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy_nodes<_Moveit>(std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *,std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *,_Moveit)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,
1>            _Moveit=std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,BaseClass::A,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,false>>::_Copy_tag
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1104): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy<std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy_tag>(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>> &,_Moveit)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,
1>            _Moveit=std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,BaseClass::A,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,false>>::_Copy_tag
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1104): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy<std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Copy_tag>(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>> &,_Moveit)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,
1>            _Moveit=std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,BaseClass::A,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>,false>>::_Copy_tag
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(1095): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>> &std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::operator =(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\map(154): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>> &std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::operator =(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\map(73): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A,
1>            _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int,BaseClass::A>>
1>        ]
1>..\..\Example.cpp(15): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<unsigned int,BaseClass::A,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=unsigned int,
1>            _Ty=BaseClass::A
1>        ]
1>Done building project "Example.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
StopOnFirstBuildError: Build cancelled because project "Example" failed to build.
Build has been canceled.
```

However, if I remove the "EXPORT_API" declaration, the error goes away.  Or if I remove the map, the error goes away.  I used thread as an example to recreate the problem without involving 3rd party APIs, but I really want to use the commented out 3rd party API found here: https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue.  It produces the same error.  I ultimately need to export the API to a DLL, but I narrowed the problem down to this much smaller piece of code.  Does anyone see the issue?

Comment: @S.M. I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::thread objects are not copyable objects, the copy constructor is deleted:

```
thread( const thread& ) = delete; (since C++11)
```

This as a member of the class A, makes the class A objects also not copyable, deletes the copy constructor of A. Finally, it makes std::pair not copyable, deletes its copy constructor, as the error reports.
Thus A can't be a value in a map. EXPORT_API does not matter.

You may use raw or shared pointers to std::thread in A.